# GNU as .macro directive expansion

Tags: assembly, macros

Is there a way to have *GNU as* only expand .macro directives in a .S file, producing another .S file without them? Similiar to what *gcc -E* does with C code.

Note this is about the assembler .macro directive like in the following code, *not* about C-style #define macros which can be expanded via cpp.

```
.macro my_macro src, so, dest
    movl    \so+10(\src), %r8d
```

Comment: Not exactly it, but try the listing option (e.g. -alms).

Comment: I found that too in the man page, but it doesn't help the problem.

Comment: From your (deleted) answer, it sounds like you might be trying to achieve "compile GNU assembler syntax files for OSX"; the last time I needed to do this, I used `objdump` and a text editor to construct a file file full of `.byte` directives. Horrible, but it worked. Mostly.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU as's preprocessor [doesn't handle](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC26) `.include` and `.macro`, as everything starting with a dot is in fact an assembler directive; thus, macro expansion is performed along program assembly, and cannot be done separately, at least by as.

You have these options:

- Search google for someone else's script
- Write your own (seems a nice programming exercise)
- Switch to C-style macros or M4

C-style macro processing is performed by default when you use the `.S` (capital s) extension for assembly files you use to feed gas, and the C preprocessor can be also invoked standalone with command `cpp`

Comment: That's a good clarification of the problem (+1), but I can't accept "find/write your own" as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use '`cpp`' to evaluate the macros instead:

`> cpp -P file.S`

or assemble after macro expansion:

`> cpp -P file.S | as -o file.o`

Comment: This does not work, because it expects C-style macros (#define). My problem is to evaluate assembler macros (.macro).