# Problems with using macro parameter in GNU assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, gnu-assembler

I'm learning GAS `macro`, and I can write some simple macros. But, I wanna join parameters to create new something, this is hard for me.

I'm not clear to understand specific `join` detail, in the beginning, I think there may be something similar compiler options `gcc -E`, so that I can learn something from it. [but It doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064701/gnu-as-macro-directive-expansion).

Below is my code, has several errors!

```
.section .data
.macro new_label name
\name\():
    .asciz "Hello World\n"
    .size \name\()_len, .-\name
.endm

.macro cat name1, name2
    new_label my_\name1\name2
.endm

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
    cat a, b

    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $my_ab, %rsi
    movq $my_ab_len, %rdx
    syscall

    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

I have these problems:

1. How to join parameter, likes above: `\name_len`.
2. I'm not sure I pass what type of parameter to macro. if I use `cat a, b`, is `a` and `b` string literal? In addition, `cat 1, 2`, `1` and `2` is integer literal or string literal?

Comment: Try `\name\()_len`.  Try `as -am` to get a listing of the macro expansions.  Refer to the manual for details.

Comment: @fuz it didn't work. error: `(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `my_ab_len'`

Comment: Please update your code in your question.  It worked for me.

Comment: @fuz OK, updated!

Comment: Read up on what the `.size` directive does.  Hint: it is not for defining labels.  Use a `.equ` directive for that.

Comment: You'll also want `movq $my_ab_len, %edx` with an immediate addressing mode instead of an absolute one.  Same for `movq $my_ab, %esi`.

Comment: @fuz It's weird, I call macro in `_start`, then the `label` is in `.text` section, and If I call macro in `.data` section, then the `label` is in `.data` section. I didn't read [it](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html#Macro).

Comment: A macro is basically text expansion.  It would be weird if the `.asciiz` *wasn't* in the section where you used the macro, since you didn't use `.pushsection .rodata` / `.popsection` inside the macro.  Instead you're just emitting that `.asciiz` into the current section at every place the macro is used.